# Update Contact details to an Opportunity through Salesforce API

Tags: salesforce

Need to create new relationship to Contact and Opportunity.
Trying to insert data to `Case_Relation__c` table for fields `Opportunity__c` `SFDC_ContactID__c`, etc. but it throws error:

> Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.

API Code:

```
  soqlQuery = "Select Case_Name__c,Case_Ranking__c,Company_Name__c,Contact_Role__c,Contact__c,Name,Opportunity__c,RUST_Case_Relationship_Legacy_ID__c,Relationship_Level__c,SFDC_ContactID__c FROM Case_Relation__c";
  SalesForceProxy.QueryResult qrR = binding.query(soqlQuery);


            done = false;

            if (qrR.size > 0)
            {
                while (!done)
                {
                    SalesForceProxy.sObject[] records = qrR.records;
                    for (int i = 0; i < records.Length; i++)
                    {
                        SalesForceProxy.Case_Relation__c con = (SalesForceProxy.Case_Relation__c)records[i];
                        oCmd.CreateParameter();

                        con.Opportunity__c = "006R0000008r0hdIAA";
                        con.SFDC_ContactID__c = "006R0000008r0hdIAA";

                        SFService.SalesForceProxy.sObject[] Case_Relation__c = new SalesForceProxy.sObject[1];
                        Case_Relation__c[0] = con;
                        if (qr.records != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                SFService.SalesForceProxy.SaveResult[] saveResults = binding.create(Case_Relation__c);
                                for (int j = 0; j < saveResults.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    if (saveResults[j].success)
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        foreach (SFService.SalesForceProxy.Error ex in saveResults[j].errors)
                                        {
                                            SendMail(ex.message);
                                            TraceService(ex.message);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                SendMail(ex.Message);
                                TraceService(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (qrR.done)
                    {
                        done = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        qrR = binding.queryMore(qrR.queryLocator);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the ***field accessibility*** for every field in  ***Case_Relation__c*** object